# Working on RStudio in Linux Mint 17

Tags: r, rstudio

I am using linux mint17 and installed RStudio but when I install some packages that error comes this is not for this version. How do I solve this problem as I am getting this problem for many packages. And my RStudio is also updated?

Comment: Can you post some error logs and code examples.

Comment: Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘ggplot2’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)

Comment: You have to update your R version. This has nothing to do with RStudio.

Comment: Okay. I got it. Thanks.

Comment: but you know when I update my R version it says "r-base is already the newest version" and start upgrading some other packages which are not related to R

Comment: I know some packages in R requires R version >= 3.1 for installation.

Comment: Linux Mint 17 was released on May 30th 2014. Do you have to use Mint 17? If not, use Mint 18 - there you get a more up to date version of R.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the R version in the default system repositories is a few minors behind (`3.0` instead of the current `3.3`, as stated by the error message). You have to make it explicit that you want to get R from a more up-to-date source.

You should add the following line:

```
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/
```

to the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`, as described at https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/#installation.
(`trusty` is the nickname of the ubuntu version Mint 17 is based on (Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr))

Then `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install r-base-dev` at the command line should update R to the current version (3.3 as of today).

Comment: Okay. I will try this and let you know the result.